# How to format Timestamp for ingesting JSON data into AWS IoT Analytics datastore using Parquet file format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, timestamp, parquet, data-ingestion, aws-iot-analytics

I'd like to ingest data into an AWS IoT Analytics datastore in Parquet format. This is how the records are in the channel.

```
{
  "Total_in": 1825.5841,
  "Time": "2023-02-17T14:08:19"
}
```

Question is, how do I need to format the time (in a transformation as part of a pipeline activity), to be used as a "timestamp" in the parquet file?

The schema of the parquet files looks like the following.

```
Column name   Data type
time          TIMESTAMP
total_in      FLOAT
```

I tried to use timestamp in seconds, in milliseconds as well as the `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` (Python) and in this case never a records gets into the data store ("Last message arrival time" is always none). If I change to `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S..%fZ` records arrive in the data store ("Last message arrival time" is not null), but if I run a query (`Select * from datastore`), then the result set is empty.

I already enabled logging, but neither the pipeline logs nor the datastore logs contain any information.

The datastore does not contain partitions/partitions are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp needs to be provided in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (eg: 2020-10-22 11:23:48).